# Repetir consulta há base de dados utilizando for em PHP

Tags: php, sql, query

Tenho a seguinte consulta

```
$turmas= $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT nome FROM turmas WHERE id= '%d' ",
        $_POST['idSerie']), ARRAY_A );
```

Quando recebo `$_POST['idSerie']` com um índice só ele funciona, porém quando recebo uma `array` não, preciso fazer um `for` para pegar cada índice, efetuar essa consulta e salvar em um outro `array`.

> Por exemplo: caso o usuário marque duas séries eu tenho que retornar as turmas dessas duas séries.

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma, só que não está funcionando.

```
$count = count($_POST['idSerie']);
$turmas[];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {       
        $turmas[] = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT nome FROM turmas WHERE id= '%d' ",
                $_POST['idSerie'][i]), ARRAY_A);        
    }
```

Comment: No caso você precisa que ele busque o `id` dentro do array que virá do `idSerie`?

Comment: sim, a variável $_POST['idSerie'] fica assim ["10", "11"], preciso separar e pesquisar as turmas com id 10 me depois turmas com id 11

Comment: então Seriam 2 consultas ou pode se fazer na mesma query ?

Comment: seria duas consultas, ou até quantas séries o usuário selecionar, se conseguir fazer isso em uma consulta só, melhor ainda, porém esse array não tem um número fixo, o usuário pode selecionar quantas séries quiser

Comment: Ta bom vou fazer de forma que seja apenas uma query ai você testa. e me da um feedback

Answer (score 0):

Criei um tratamento para verificar se o `$_POST[]` recebido é um array ou não, caso for ele concatena os `ids` e prepara para query, caso não ele simplesmente insere na query

```
$count = count($_POST['idSerie']);
$id_query = '';
if(is_array($_POST['idSerie'])){

    foreach ($_POST['idSerie'] as $key => $value) {
        $id_query+=  $value.', ';
    }
    $id_query = substr($id_query, 0, -2);
}else {
    $id_query = $_POST['idSerie'];
}      

$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT nome FROM turmas WHERE id IN ({$id_query}) "),ARRAY_A) ;
```

Nesse exemplo eu vou buscar com base em todos os ids, caso queria separado da para acertar dentro da `query`, usando `order by id`, ou fazendo um looping de querys (não recomendo).

Comment: eu salvei esse valor dentro de uma variavel $teste = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT nome FROM turmas WHERE id IN ('%d') ", $id_query),ARRAY_A); e coloco em um array para mandar por json, só que ele retorna duas vezes arrays vazios assim: {Array(0)}, ele tem que juntar essa consulta em um array só e mandar uma vez

Comment: Me faz um favor, ne essa variável `$wpdb` roda um `var_dump($wpdb);` nela posta o resultado para eu ver o que está retornando.

Comment: fiz uma atualização me retorna o teste dessa atualização que fiz. por favor.